# Issue with accessing RxMap value in GetX controller in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

**Issue with accessing RxMap value in GetX controller in Flutter**

I'm encountering an issue while working with GetX in my Flutter project. I have a LoginController that uses GetX for state management. Within this controller, I have a variable user of type RxMap<dynamic, dynamic>. In my HomeAppBar widget, I'm trying to access the user variable from the controller using Obx, but I'm facing difficulties in accessing its value.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// LoginController
class LoginController extends GetxController {
  var user = {}.obs;

  void userExists(String phoneNumberTyped) async {
    try {
      var responseData = await networkRepository.checkUser(number: phoneNumberTyped);
      user.value = responseData['body'];
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
    }
  }
}

// HomeAppBar
class HomeAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeAppBar({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final LoginController loginController = Get.put(LoginController());

    return Obx(() {
      RxMap<dynamic, dynamic> userData = loginController.user;

      return Column(
        children: [
          Text(userData.toString(),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to access the value property of the user variable within the HomeAppBar widget. When I try to access userData.value.toString(), I'm getting an error saying that 'value' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_iterables/rx_map.dart'.

How can I properly access the value of the user variable within my HomeAppBar widget?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use like this it will work.

```
class HomeAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeAppBar({Key? key});

  final loginController = Get.put(LoginController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Column(
        children: [
         Obx(() => Text(loginController.user.value.toString()))// use can access value like this loginController.user["name"]
        ],
      );
  }
}
```